# How do I set two values for IE's `filter` property?

Tags: css

I have an issue that seems to have a [workaround available](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/transparent-png-shows-black-edges-in-ie8#14737000001521474).  I need to set two values using IE's propriety `filter` property in CSS.

I have...

```
element {
   filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)
}
```

The second `filter` seems to be overwriting the first, which is what I would expect.

How can I set them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly, but why do you want to use both?

This does both opacity and gradient.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=Look,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)
```

Looking at `#00FFFFFF`, The first 2 `00` controls opacity and the last 6 digits controls color.

### Check working example http://jsfiddle.net/fG3dQ/

Comment: I wasn't aware the first 2 were opacity.

Comment: That's exactly what they are for. Try for example 55 instead of the 00 and see how opacity changes. You can do that for either end

Comment: @Hussein I believe you, I was just saying I wasn't aware of it until I read your answer. No need to be defensive :)

Comment: Uh no. I meant it in a non defensive way. I edited it right away realizing it could be taken this way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma!

```
element {
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF), alpha(opacity=40)
}
```

Works for me in IE7.